# Table with check option with sub of checked rows

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I Have Table With check box in my nodejs project with ejs view where third column have some number value I want Total Of Number where checkbox are checked 
I could not understand how to get rows which are checked and also I don't want to use Jquery

I have tried below code which did not work

```
function getSelected() {
var table = document.getElementById("t1"),sumVal = 0;
            sumVal = sumVal || 0

var checkBoxes =  table.getElementById("selction");

for(var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++)
                {
                if (checkBoxes[i].checked)
                {
                var row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;  

                var sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(row.cell[3].innerHTML);

                }
                }
 document.getElementById("val").innerHTML =  sumVal;
 console.log(row);

}
</script>
```

My ejs file is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta charset="windows-1252">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(source) {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i] != source)
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
}
</script
<body>
<h1>Payment Entry</h1>
<div class="w3-container w3-border-top w3-border-bottom">


<table class="w3-table-all w3-hoverable">

<thead>
<tr class="w3-hover-orange">
<th><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this);" /></th>
<th>Truck No</th>
<th>Cr Date</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Collected By</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="t1">
<tr class="w3-hover-yellow">
<td><input  type="checkbox" onclick="getSelected()" name="selction" id="selction"></td>
<td>data</td>
<td>data</td>
<td>10000</td>
<td>data</td>
</tr>
<tr class="w3-hover-yellow">
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="getSelected()" name="selction" id="selction"></td>
<td>data</td>
<td>data</td>
<td >20000</td>
<td>data</td>
</tr>
<tr class="w3-hover-yellow">
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="getSelected()" name="selction" id="selction"></td>
<td>data</td>
<td>data</td>
<td>30000</td>
<td>data</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr class="w3-hover-orange">
<td>Total</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><label id= "val"/> </td>
<td></td>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

I want Total Value Add To Total When I check checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working solution is following:

```
function getSelected() {
  let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(
    '#t1 input[type="checkbox"]:checked'
  );
  let sum = 0;
  for (let checkbox of checkboxes) {
    let row = checkbox.parentElement.parentElement;
    let value = row.children[3].textContent;
    sum += Number(value);
  }
  document.querySelector("#val").textContent = sum;
}

function toggle(source) {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#t1 input[type="checkbox"]');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
  getSelected();
}
```

As a fast workaround I just added a call to `getSelected()` in `toggle` function.

Comment: Dear Sir this code is working when I am checking checkbox one by one but when i am using toggle source function for selecting all checkbox together it is not working also when I checked some checkbox  by mistake and unchecked it total is not reversing

Comment: What do you mean by "total is not reversing"?

Comment: when i checked column 1 and 2 total is 40000 but when i unchecked column 1 total is still 40000 instead of 10000

Comment: demo is working correctly let me re-check if I have some typing mismatch or something like that in my codes

Comment: I have checked it's working correctly may be I have made some mistake earlier but it's working correctly thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses an eventListener on the "source" checkbox and on each of the "selection" checkboxes.
It removes the use of the same `id` value on multiple elements (which can cause serious problems.)

It also makes use of:
 - the `.closest` method to find the row,
 - the `.children` property to get the cells in the row, and
 - the `for...of` statement to loop through the "selection" inputs

```js
// Globals
const source = document.getElementById("source"),
      checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("selection"),
      result = document.getElementById("result");

// Listeners
source.addEventListener("change", toggleAll)
for (let box of checkboxes){
  box.addEventListener("change", updateTotal);
}

// Functions
function toggleAll() {
  for(let box of checkboxes){
    box.checked = source.checked;
  }
  updateTotal();
}

function updateTotal(){
  let currentTotal = 0;
  for(let box of checkboxes){
    if (box.checked){
      var row = box.closest("TR");  
      currentTotal += parseInt(row.children[3].innerHTML);
    }
  }
  result.innerHTML = currentTotal;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Payment Entry</h1>
  <div class="w3-container w3-border-top w3-border-bottom">
    <table class="w3-table-all w3-hoverable">
      <thead>
        <tr class="w3-hover-orange">
          <th><input type="checkbox" id="source" /></th>
          <th>Truck No</th>
          <th>Cr Date</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Collected By</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr class="w3-hover-yellow">
          <td><input  type="checkbox" name="selection" /></td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>10000</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="w3-hover-yellow">
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="selection" /></td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td >20000</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="w3-hover-yellow">
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="selection" /></td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>30000</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr class="w3-hover-orange">
          <td>Total</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><label id="result">0</label></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```